# how to extract data from a txt file into a dataframe using python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-extraction

[image]Hi I want to colect data from a txt file in order to create a dataframe of 3 columns using python

a column for the name of my file 'f' which holds the name of the molecules
a column for the values of the  ' Zero-point correction'
a column for the values of the 'Sum of electronic and zero-point Energies'

in order to have a table like this:

Molecule      Zero-point correction      Sum of electronic and zero-Energies

.                 .                               .
.                               .
.                 .                               .
.

here is my code:

```
import os
import pandas as pd
files = [f for f in os.listdir(".") if '.out' in f]
words = [' Zero-point correction', 'Sum of electronic and zero-point Energies']


for f in files:
    with open(f, 'r') as file:
          lines = file.readlines()
          for line in lines:
            for word in words:  
             if word in line:
                  a,b = line.split('=')
                 
                  print(a,b,f)
```

I've found my data but i dont know how to put hem into a dataframe

```
 Zero-point correction                            0.171551 (Hartree/Particle)
 O-1.out
 Sum of electronic and zero-point Energies            -738.826005
 O-1.out
```

.
.
.
......

Answer (score 0):

what is the data structure of the file?

one way of doing the following -> but it depends on your data structure in the file/files we are reading

```
import os
import pandas as pd
files = [f for f in os.listdir(".") if '.out' in f]
words = [' Zero-point correction', 'Sum of electronic and zero-point Energies']


col = words.append("file")
df = pd.DataFrame(columns= col )

for f in files:
    with open(f, 'r') as file:
          lines = file.readlines()
          for line in lines:
            for word in words:  
             if word in line:
                  a,b = line.split('=')
                 
                  print(a,b,f)
                  df.loc[len(df)] = [a,b,f]
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/lenovo/Desktop/travail été 2022/calcul/ZPE for O B3LYP 6-31Gd/import os2.py", line 16, in <module>
    a,b = line.split('=')
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)   I got this error

Comment: check that the data is uniform -> the line might not include a "="